# Grouping N person randomly but evenly? (Name & Gender)

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, grouping

So, I tried to create an algorithm(?) to assign a person to a classroom. The requirement for each class is :

1. Have at least 30 people and maximum of 45
2. The person name will not be "Homogen" (e.g: class 1 - 3 has all person name started with the letter "A", while class 4-5 the letter "B" etc.)
3. The gender is also evenly distributed
4. If the class is full, the remaining person will be moved to waiting list

My data has the column Unique ID, Name, and Gender. I'm still new to this kind of stuff (Algorithm?) so I don't even know where to start. Is it even possible? Where do I start? I am using PHP and my data is in MySQL Database

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry That's the problem. I can't figure out any way to make this work as I stated. This is new to me. And the data is just a dummy data for now, or should I also provide a dummy data for this? anyway, do you know where should I start?

Comment: I guess when you shuffle the array of persons, and then start assigning to classes you'll get a good result on average. Maybe you'll have a different count of males and females in your input, so then this will also reflect in the expected ratio in a class. Maybe your input will consist of all names starting with only A or B: this also will reflect in the distribution. The rules are quite open for interpretation.

Comment: Pick all the males and shuffle them. Do the same with the females and zipper join them. That'll give you equal distribution between the two.

Comment: I would do the class assignments in PHP, not SQL. Get two lists of unassigned students sorted by name - one for each gender, then step through the lists assigning students from the 1st list, then the 2nd, and so on until each class is full or the letter changes.

Comment: Your requirement for non-homogeneity means this: you don't want random selection. You want a selection with the cognitive appearance of randomness. That is an entirely diferent thing.  If you want to automate this you'll need to develop measures of homogeneity both for names and genders. You'll then need to generate a series of random assignments. You'll then need to measure them for homogeneity and reject each one that's too homogeneous, and keep going until you get one that passes your tests.  Read this for info. https://www.wired.com/2012/12/what-does-randomness-look-like/

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks! that doesn't come up to my mind.

Comment: @O.Jones Well, I simply want to group data and evenly distribute it. The only randomness that I need is when trying to make sure that a full classroom member name doesn't start with the same letter

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yep, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. But I can't come up with a logic that distributes the data without creating a classroom that all the name start with the same letter. Thankfully the idea from h2ooooooo might work

Comment: @trincot Yeah, I know it's very dependant on the data to start with, but I think about it this way, if the data has every person name begin with letter A, then at least make sure the person with the same name doesn't belong to the same class.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question item #2. In that case, getting a list of male, and a list of female students in a random order, then "shuffling" the two lists together should work. @h2oooooooo answer should work. Just use PHP to manage class sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1

You need to get data from DateBase (all people)

```
$host = '***';
$user = '***'';
$password = '***'';
$database = '***'';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Error" . mysqli_error($link));
$query = "SELECT * FROM people";

$people = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error" . mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_close($link);
```

### Step 2

Conver mysql_result to Array and shuffle it.

```
$people = [];
foreach ($result as $person) {
    $people[] = $person;
}
shuffle($people);
```

### Step 3

There is algorithm:

```
$count = count($people);
// Classes
$classes = [];
const MIN_SIZE = 30;
const MAX_SIZE = 45;


$maxSizeClass= $count / MIN_SIZE;
$minSizeClass= $count / MAX_SIZE;

$countClasses = max(ceil($minSizeClass), floor($maxSizeClass));
$currentCountClass = $count / $countClasses;

$tmpClass = [];
foreach ($people as $person) {
    if (count($tmpClass) < $currentCountClass) {
        $tmpClass[] = $person;
    } else {
        $classes[] = $tmpClass;
        $tmpClass = [];
    }
}

if (count($tmpClass) >= MIN_SIZE) {
    $classes[] = $tmpClass;
    $tmpClass = [];
}

foreach ($tmpClass as $index => $person) {
    foreach ($classes as &$class) {
        if (count($class) < MAX_SIZE) {
            $class[] = $person;
            // be careful, PHP7 is OK
            unset($tmpClass[$index]);
            continue 2;
        }
    }
}

// persons awaiting distribution
$waitingQueue = $tmpClass;
```

### Step 4

Result is:

`$waitingQueue` - persons awaiting distribution

`$classes` - classes with persons

Comment: I don't think you should be picking a random class size - presumably, you should be optimizing for as few people waiting as possible

Comment: I have updated answer. Now I optimized for the minimum number of waiting people

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm! It's better than what I worked

Answer (score 0):

```
$letters = array('a','b',....,'y','z');
foreach($letters as $letter){
    $sql['male'] = "SELECT * FROM people_table WHERE person_name LIKE '".$letter."%' AND person_gender = 'male' ORDER BY person_name";
    $sql['female'] = "SELECT * FROM people_table WHERE person_name LIKE '".$letter."%' AND person_gender = 'female' ORDER BY person_name";
    foreach($sql as $key => $query){
        $results[$key] = $connection->query($query);
        for($i = 0; $i < $results[$key]->num_rows; $i++){
            $people[$letter][$key][] = results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have the lists of people listed by gender by letter... Now we can loop it and insert a man and a woman by pairs. If the `count();` of the list of pairs is lesser than 30, people wait more. If bigger than 44 (because in pair isn't possible to have 45 people, if I don't missunderstand the question, of course) then save this 44 in a class array `$class[$letter]` which you can see all classes by each letter. To know about how many classes you have in total, you can use `count($class);` or if you would like to know how many classes of a specific letter you can do `count($class[$letter]);`.

You can redo other `foreach` in the `$letters` array or just put the loop inside the `foreach`above to create the array of classes.
Inside the `foreach($letters as $letter){}` at the final:

```
if( !(count($people[$letter][$key]) < 15 OR count($people[$letter][$key]) < 15) ){
    $she = count($people[$letter]['female'];
    $he = count($people[$letter]['male'];
    if($she < $he){
        for($i = 0; $i < 2*count($she); $i++){
            $class[$letter][$i] = $people[$letter]['female'][$i];
            $class[$letter][$i+1] = $people[$letter]['male'][$i];
            $i++;//Important to avoid replace values!
        }
    } else {
        for($i = 0; $i < 2*count($he); $i++){
            $class[$letter][$i] = $people[$letter]['female'][$i];
            $class[$letter][$i+1] = $people[$letter]['male'][$i];
            $i++;//Important to avoid replace values!
        }
}
```

A false boolean in the bigger `if` means cannot create a class with this letter gender evenly distributed. You can loop again to make each class in an entry of an array.